# Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 SDK 10.0.15063 _scale-100.appx not found

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I just updated to Windows 10 SDK 10.0.15063 and running into a problem creating app packages for the Windows Store. It seems to complete the x86 and x64 portion, but fails for the ARM portion:

> Error: File 'C:\somepath\bin\ARM\Release\App_1.1.218.0_scale-100.appx' not found.

Using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Not even sure where to begin on how to fix this. Any thoughts?

Comment: These kind of questions need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: You're not the only one with this problem. It started happening to me yesterday after the VS update. I ended up making a new project file and transferred everything over and I still get the error so i'm guessing MS goofed again.

Comment: Yep same problem here starting today, definitely getting the feeling this is an MS issue

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40376/error-file-csomepathbinarmreleaseapp-112180-scale.html?childToView=40706#comment-40706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug fix included in VS 2017 Version 15.1 26403.7

Answer (score 17):

I copied the temporary workaround from the link Carlo Mendoza provided:

1. Download and extract [storepackageworkaround.zip](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/4321-storepackageworkaround.zip) to any location.
2. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
3. Open the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017 in Administrator mode.
4. In the command prompt, navigate to the location where you extracted these files.
5. Run Apply.cmd.

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me. The exact cause is unknown, but it was something to do with your app getting locked by the operating system. Try the following:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Uninstall your app. (Start -> Your app icon -> right-click -> uninstall)
3. Delete all "bin" & "obj" folders from your solution directory.
4. Open solution in Visual Studio again and create app packages.

This used to work for me. Again, there might be a faster trick.. or an actual remedy.

Comment: Attempted this, not working with the latest VS 2017 unfortunately

Comment: @Laith, I think that's a different problem, but also very familiar with and equally annoyed by it. #3 does the job for that.

Answer (score 0):

I got around a similar problem with not finding windows.h by right clicking on the project, and retargeting the windows version to the previous one. 10.0.14393.0